# How to centre a swf file on different screen resoutions?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Does any one know how to center a swf file which crops off each side rather than only the right to keep it centered in different screen resolutions?

I would like it to be similar to this site's banner http://www.mondoliving.com.au/ If you change the screen resolution or browser window size the image stays in the center but does not scale only the width shown seems to change by cropping on each side.

I have tried using javascript which works for different screen resolutions but first loads the swf on the left then centers it which appears to jump into the center.  I was wondering if anyone new a different, smoother way to do it?  I was wondering if it might be done with Action script within the swf??

The javascript I used was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function centerSWF()
{
 var sw;
 if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>3)
 {
  if(navigator.appName=="Netscape"){sw = window.innerWidth-17;}
  if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1){sw = document.body.offsetWidth-0;}
  }
 var w = (sw-1500)/2;
 document.getElementById("flashbg").style.width = sw+"px";
 document.getElementById("flash").style.marginLeft = w+"px";
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="centerSWF()">
```

then I embedded the swf.

Embedded code:

```
<div id="flash_box">
<div id="flashbg" class="flashbg">
 <div id="flash" class="flash">
      <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1500" height="250">
        <param name="movie" value="img/top14.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="scale" value="noborder" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
        <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
        <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="img/top14.swf" width="1500" height="250">
          <!--<![endif]-->
          <param name="quality" value="high" />
          <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
         <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
         <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
         <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
          <div>
           <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
          </div>
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End flash_box -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#flash_box {
margin:auto;
padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
border-bottom:double #e9e8e8 thin;
border-collapse:collapse;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.flashbg{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;}
.flash{width:1500px;}
```

Thanks
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the HTML of embedded code

Comment: Sorry I have added it to the post,

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in CSS -

```
#flash_box {
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
border-bottom:double #e9e8e8 thin;
border-collapse:collapse;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
}
.flashbg{/*position:absolute;overflow:hidden;*/}
.flash{width:1500px; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Did you mean leave the javascript in or without?

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for alignment here

Comment: No the swf is sitting left not centering at all.  When I was trying to figure it out before I did get it to center but it would not stay centered if the window or screen resolution was smaller.  I only had it in two divs (flashbox and swfcontainer)and I think my css was this: `code`#flash_box {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-bottom:double #e9e8e8 thin;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 }

.swfContainer {
 text-align: center;
 width:1500px;
 height:250px;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
  
}